# Android: pass a value to a class

Tags: java, android, class

I have this code and I want to pass an int to this class:

```
if (content_timer.getChildCount() != 0) content_timer.removeAllViews();
                content_timer.addView(new CircleTimer(getApplicationContext()));
```

then I have "new CircleTimer(getApplicationContext())" that instance a class but I want pass at this class a value, what can I do?

Comment: can you show me an example please...

Answer (score 1):

```
if (content_timer.getChildCount() != 0) content_timer.removeAllViews();
                content_timer.addView(new CircleTimer(getApplicationContext(),10));
                                                                             ^^^^^^
```

**edit your class**

```
public class CircleTimer
{
int a;
    public CircleTimer(Context cxt, int a) <------
    {
       this.a =a;
    }
.....
}
```